# Is float better than double sometimes?

Tags: c, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I was solving this problem on spoj http://www.spoj.com/problems/ATOMS/. I had to give the integral part of log(m / n) / log(k) as output. I had taken m, n, k as long long. When I was calculating it using long doubles, I was getting a wrong answer, but when I used float, it got accepted.

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long)(log(m / (long double)n) / log(k)));
```

This was giving a wrong answer but this:

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long)((float)log(m / (float)n) / (float)log(k)));
```

got accepted. So are there situations when float is better than double with respect to precision?

Comment: it's not that `float` is "better" than `double`. You should take rounding errors into account when converting a floating-point number to an integer. That's not as simple as casting it away.

Comment: How do I safely convert a floating-point number to an integer? @The Paramagnetic Croissant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `float` is *never* more accurate than a `double` since the former must be a subset of the latter, by the C standard:

6.2.5/6: "The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double."

Note that the standard does *not* insist on a particular floating point representation although IEEE754 is particularly common.

Answer (score 1):

double will always give you more precision than a float.
With double, you encode the number using 64 bits, while your using only 32 bits with float.

Edit: As Jens mentioned it may not be the case. double will give more precision only if the compiler is using IEEE-754. That's the case of GCC, Clang and MSVC. I haven't yet encountered a compiler which didn't use 32 bits for floats and 64 bits for doubles though...

Comment: That's wrong. Doubles and floats may use the same number of bits (i.e. be indistinguishable) and they need not be a multiple of 32. Do not extrapolate from the one implementation you are familiar with :-)

Comment: That's true. It's only the case if the compiler is complying with IEEE-754. I have never encountered a compiler that didn't though.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better in some cases in terms of calculation time/space performance. One example that is just on the table in front of me - an ARM Cortex-M4F based microcontroller, having a hardware Floating Point Unit (FPU), capable of working with single-precision arithmetic, but not with double precision, which is giving an incredible boost to floating point calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float i=3.3;
    if(i==3.3)
      printf("Equal\n");
    else
      printf("Not Equal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now try the same with double as a datatype of i.

Comment: With all due respect...the code works well without the edit as well.

Comment: You can kill mosquitoes with a 5kg hammer. Works well? Yes. Correct? No.

Comment: Correct is relative. You have'nt specified the number of mosquitoes here. If there are enough mosquitoes lined up in a certain area and 5 Newton is the exact force required to kill all of them at one go in unit velocity per unit area, then its obviously correct.

Comment: Ok, I see that metaphors don't work here. So in programming and not only, there are a good and bad practices. I is *wrong* to use the bad practices, and *correct* to use the good ones. Even if *accidentally* both are yielding the same correct result in a specific case.

Comment: As for the code i added - it was optimally written.The additions were simply not required.

Comment: `void main()` is simply wrong according to C standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip.Will keep that in mind.PS:Its good that you gave up on the metaphors.